# how to specify Node Label with yarn restful api

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I have seted several node labels in YARN, but I failed to create the application through the [YARN restful API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Applications_API.28Submit_Application.29). The application status is ACCEPTED and the default `AM Container Node Label expression` is `<DEFAULT_PARTITION>`.

```
YarnApplicationState:                   ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM. 
Unmanaged Application:                  false
Application Node Label expression:      <DEFAULT_PARTITION>
AM container Node Label expression:     <DEFAULT_PARTITION>
```

The `DEFAULT_PARTITION` has no resources， but my other node labels have resources.

```
<DEFAULT_PARTITION>     Exclusive Partition     0       <memory:0, vCores:0>
common                  Exclusive Partition     170     <memory:29593600, vCores:13600>
```

**How do I specify the `Common` node label? Or if there is another way to submit applications via restful apis?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. According to the doc, you can only specify queue and priority.

However, maybe you can try to specify it via `am-container-spec >> command`

```
$YOUR_APP_COMMAND -Dyarn.application.queue=default -Dyarn.application.node-label=common
```

Comment: maybe the code could be formatted